# Launch Android app on specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that uses `SectionsPagerAdapter` to show 3 fragments within an activity (this part was automatically generated by Android Studio after selecting a tabbed activity). Right now, this is how I select what fragment to show:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new Fragment1();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new Fragment2();
            } else {
                return new Fragment3();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
}
```

I would like my app to start on Fragment 2 (i.e. `position 1`), to allow the user to either swipe right to go back to the first fragment, or to swipe left to move on to the next fragment.

How can I set the position to start at? I couldn't find any method to set the position number, is there one or should I do this another way?

If it helps, this is my `onCreateView` method of my `MainActivity` class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an Activity has `onCreateView` method. Its a method of a fragment. Your activity will have  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

If my assumptions are not wrong, in the layout of your main activity you will have a android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.

and in your code you might declare your view pager variable and set the SectionsPagerAdapter to it. After that just do   `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`

Comment: Yep, sorry, I should have clarified. The `onCreateView` method belongs to the placeholder fragment class, which is inside my main activity.

Comment: Its fine. Did the setCurrentItem helps ?

Comment: @user1301428 It happens. Have fun developing with android.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set the position to start at?

Call [`setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29).

Comment: Wizardry! That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!